# Powershell - Set-TimeZone

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to set the TimeZone to "automatic" via Powershell!
Is this possible?
Here is the doc: [Microsoft Docs - Set-TimeZone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-timezone?view=powershell-7.2)
[image]

Comment: see what it is set to

Comment: Yes, i know what you mean - But i dont want to set an ID - i really want that automatic thing - if its possible - it looks like an setting that correlates with the region or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with a powershell cmdlet to set the TimeZone to automatic but I do know you can set it via Registry editing or GPO.

You can set via registry per below, please reference the following link for more informaiton: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/shell-experience/cannot-set-timezone-automatically

**Note:** The standard be careful when messing with the registry disclaimer applies. You can seriously break your OS if you mess with the wrong things. *Be careful!*

```
$TZAutoSettingRegPath = "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\tzautoupdate"
Set-ItemProperty -Path $TZAutoSettingRegPath -Name "Start" -Value 3
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Thats exactly what i needed.